# value computed is not used, " How to solve the warning "

Tags: c++

// In the below Code, Getting warning, How to clear the warning ?

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<sizeof(array) / sizeof(string); i++,*ptr++)  // warning. 
    {
        cout<<*ptr<<", ";
    }
    cout <<endl;

    string *ptr1 = &array[0];
    string *ptr2 = &array[2];

    while(1)
    {
        cout<<*ptr1 <<", ";
        if(ptr1==ptr2)
            break;
        *ptr1++;        // Warning 
    }
```

Comment: `*ptr1++;` is same as `ptr1++;` if you don't use the result. Was that your intent?

Answer (score 0):

Because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `*ptr++` is evaluated as  `*(ptr++)`.

that is, "dereference the result of `ptr++`". But, as the warning says, you never use the dereferenced value.

---

You have two options:

1. If you want to increment `ptr` (i.e. change where it's pointing to) use `ptr++`.
2. If you want to incremend the value pointed to by by `ptr` use `(*ptr)++`

Most likely you want the first one.